# Problem adding a List inside a List on C# ADO.NET

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am trying to add a List inside a new List using C# and I get the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'A type that implements IEnumerable 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

I tried a few methods to implement it but it didn't go trough.
This is what I have done:

```
public List<ExtendEmp> GetEmpDatas()
{
    var result2 = from emp in db.employees
                  join dep in db.departments on emp.departmentID equals dep.ID
                  orderby emp.ID

                  select new ExtendEmp
                  {
                      ID = emp.ID,
                      fname = emp.fname,
                      lname = emp.lname,
                      startWorkYear = emp.startWorkYear,
                      name = dep.name,
                      manager = dep.manager,
                      ExtendShiftz = new List<ExtendShft>()

                  };
    return result2.ToList();
}
```

The specific list I'm trying to add is `ExtendShiftz` which is initialised here:

```
public List<ExtendShft> GetShftDatas()
{
    var result3 = from emp in db.employees
                  join emps in db.employee_shift on emp.ID equals emps.employeeid
                  join shft in db.shifts on emps.shiftid equals shft.ID
                  select new ExtendShft
                  {
                      ID = shft.ID,
                      employeeid = emps.employeeid,
                      fname = emp.fname,
                      lname = emp.lname,
                      shiftid = emps.shiftid,
                      date = shft.date,
                      startTime = shft.startTime,
                      endTime = shft.endTime
                  };
    return result3.ToList();
}
```

and of course i added it inside my model that way:

```
public ExtendEmp()
{
    ExtendShiftz = new List<ExtendShft>();
}
public List<ExtendShft> ExtendShiftz { get; set; }
```

If you guys have any idea what i am doing wrong there i'd be happy to read.

Comment: You have to post all classes that you are trying to use in your queries and tell us what do you want to have in the end.

Comment: Are all of the properties you are assigning to `ExtendEmp` (lname, fname, etc.) defined in your class? A thought: Since you have this line in your constructor: `ExtendShiftz = new List<ExtendShft>();`, you may not need to assign it a value in the Linq query.